# How to use Lightblue bean to associate with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, lightblue

I am a newbie that I want to use Lightblue bean to associate with arduino. But the problem is I can't get the Arduino app because of the unclick form. I check the version of arduino by wonder but it didn't work and the problem still confused me.
Be appreciated by anyone who can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
This may be caused by the outdated version of Arduino app.

I've solved it by downloading the latest version of Arduino app and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks!
I have solved it by downloading Arduino 1.6.5. I found it happened on Mac but not Windows, just don't know why XD